# Android: PY4A (SL4A): How to know when wifi scan is complete after wifiStartScan()?

Tags: android, python, wifi, sl4a, network-scan

Using PY4A under SL4A, after initiating a wifi scan via wifiStartScan(), how can I know when the scan is complete, so I can then get the most up-to-date info via wifiGetScanResults()?

There doesn't seem to be any event that is triggered when the scan has completed, but perhaps I'm missing something.

The code excerpt below illustrates the issue I'm having.

By the way, I know how to do this in Java under Android. I want to solve this problem specifically using PY4A, however.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
import android
a = android.Android()
scanStarted = a.wifiStartScan()
if scanStarted:
    ###
    ### How do I wait for the wifi scan to complete?
    ###
    scanResults = a.wifiGetScanResults()
    # process wifi scan results here
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the below with pretty good success on a S4.  I call the Def every time I need a new results.

```
    def getwifi():
    try:    
    droid.wifiStartScan()
    time.sleep(3)
    ap = droid.wifiGetScanResults()
    aps = ap.result
    return str(aps)
    except:
    print "Wifi Scan Failed"
```

Comment: Thank you, this will work most of the time, but simply sleeping for a few seconds is a race condition. I was hoping for some sort of way to positively detect that the scan is finished ... say, via some sort of event. But given that no one has offered such a solution, I'm guessing that it isn't possible.